# exception thrown while connecting to database: connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#

I am trying basic database insert and this code is waht I am running in visual studio 2010:-

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WebSite3\\App_Data\\name.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into names values('" + TextBox1.Text + "')");
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

where am I wrong?

Comment: You didn't add the connection to the SqlCommand - `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into names values('" + TextBox1.Text + "')", conn);` or `cmd.Connection = conn;`.  Also, learn parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not assign the [connection to the command object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). try:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WebSite3\\App_Data\\name.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into names values('" + TextBox1.Text + "')");
    cmd.Connection = conn; // <- this is the missing line
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a connection and opened it, but you did not associate it with the `SqlCommand`.  You can do this a couple of ways, either in the constructor of the `SqlCommand` or through the `Connection` property of the `SqlCommand`.

Additionally, you should use parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection attacks. I'd also recommend putting the `SqlConnection` in a using block to ensure it is closed and properly disposed of.  Putting all of that together gives you something like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WebSite3\\App_Data\\name.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into names values(@name)", conn);
        // Alternatively, you could do cmd.Connection = conn if you didn't pass
        // the connection object into the SqlCommand constructor
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```